# Efficiently join two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables sharing the same attribute 'attr'. The domain of values in attribute 'attr' in Table cust are a subset of domain of values in attribute 'attr' in table sales. 
E.g Table cust containing 940, 8575, 454, 86869, 856869, 9686 as values in attribute 'attr', while Table sales contains 454, 86869, 856869, 8756, 5324, 946707, 9779. Also table cust contains 1 billion rows while Table sale contains 1 trillion rows. In order to perform the join I tried the following command:

```
select * from cust where cust.attr in(select distinct attr from table sales)
```

However, this turns out to be very slow..is there some efficient way to perform the join

Comment: is attr is indexed on both the tables ?

Comment: no attr is not indexes. I think a good way is to index it :)

Comment: yes once you do index its better to select data in chunnk with limit using join this will also increase the performance.

Comment: also make sure that the attr col is having the same size and data type in both tables in order to have the index working while joining.

Answer (score 1):

1 billion rows !! ... 1 trillion rows !!

Create index on attr column in both the tables

```
ALTER TABLE cust ADD INDEX (attr);
ALTER TABLE sales ADD INDEX (attr);
```

Then do join using below syntax.

```
select * from cust c
inner join sales s
on c.attr=s.attr
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT cust.* 
FROM cust 
INNER JOIN sales attr
ON sales.attr = cust.attr
WHERE [query conditions here]
```

Make sure cust.attr and sales.attr are indexed, too

This post on JOINs will be helpful: http://webduos.com/mysql-join-syntax/